# Using D3 from another website in my demo site

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Please take a look at this awesome project:
http://d3-generator.com

I want exactly the same thing for a demo for tomorrow BUT I Must use **R2D3** instead of D3.
https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/
R2D3 is almost the same as D3, your codes from D3 most of them just work in R2D3 too. But Like I said I need to use R2D3 and that D3-Generator is exactly the demo I need.

How can I use its source code and create a demo for myself just like that **But with R2D3** instead of D3? If it was D3 I could just demo directly from that URL.

Answer (score 2):

R2D3 is nothing more than shimmed version of D3 to make it work in Internet Explorer 7 & 8.  You should be able to run the generator to get a snippet of D3 code. Then include that script, along with the conditional script to load R2D3 for IE, and standard D3 for every other modern browser.

R2D3 was built this way so you can remove it with 0 impact to your codebase once you don't care about IE 7 & 8. Using ONLY R2D3 is a bad idea, as that means your visualization will only work in old versions of internet explorer. R2D3 was built with the assumption its running in Internet Explorer